# Hide div if scrollLeft of container is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a div that scrolls using navigation buttons for a fluid width page, but I am quite new to Javascript and I'm having trouble with using scrollLeft = 0 to hide the left-most nav button if there is nothing to be scrolled, and to show the div if it has width to be scrolled. I've been searching for awhile, and most of what I've found only seems relevant to document scroll and not a container.

Here is what I have so far, I hope it's not too awful.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var scrollFunc = function() {
    var scrollLeft = $(.Titan).scrollLeft();
    if(scrollLeft = $(.Titan).scrollLeft{
    $(#left-select2).hideDiv();
    else(scrollLeft != $(.Titan).scrollLeft{
    $(#left-select2).showDiv();
    };
    });
</script>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is checking if the div is fully scrolled left (a value of 0), and if it is, to hide div `#left-select2`. If it isn't, to show it. Again. I'm sorry if it's riddled with bugs.

Comment: This appears to be jQuery. Please add that information to your title and tags.

Comment: Your code is full of errors... missing quotes, missing parentheses...

Answer (score 1):

Your code it quite flawed, but the following removes all of your errors and works with the class and ID you gave

```
$('.Titan').scroll(function() {// Fires each time the container is scrolled
    if($(this).scrollLeft() == 0) {
        $('#left-select2').hide();// Fires when the container is at its left 
                                   // most scroll position
    }
    else if($('#left-select2').css('display') != 'block') {
        $('#left-select2').show(); // Fires when the container is at any other
                                   // scroll position and the element is hidden
    }
}).scroll(); // Fires the scroll function to start so it is correct on load
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8neF/1/)

Things to note:

- Your code should be within a `scroll` function for the container
- You *have* to close the if statements with closing parenthesis
- You *have* to close bracketed functions with closing brackets
- The correct jQuery functions are `hide` and `show`, not `hideDiv` and
  `showDiv` (unless they're your custom functions)
- `scrollLeft` returns the left scroll position, you shouldn't have
  brackets after it

Comment: Just browsing through but your demo was not working for me when I looked at it because jQuery was not a loaded script - I updated it - http://jsfiddle.net/L8neF/1/

Comment: @Sarah Thanks, my fault for not including it xD

Answer (score 0):

jQuery syntax is `hide()`, not `hideDiv()`.